# GPU Tensorflow Installation

Tags: linux, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, gpu

What does it mean when you install tensorflow using `pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]` and get the below outputs.

Output 1:

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

When you run `import tensorflow as tf`.

Output 2: When I run `print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))`, I get the below output `Num GPUs Available:  0` (this should be 2). With the below warning message

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2251] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

I followed the instructions on the [tensorflow docs page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions). This is on a linux 64 bit.

[image: Output file]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.